# Swagger Можно ли документировать проект, а не только часть RestAPi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Может ли Swagger документировать не только ту часть проекта что связана с restApi, на и некоторые внутренние объекты, к примеру некоторые сервисы и прочие ? Хотелось бы добавить по мимо документации апис еще и документацию внутренних методов и объектом и вынести их в отдельный пункт который из комбо бокса "Select Defenition" можно выбрать. возможно ли подобное ? Если нет то какие альтернативы Swagger Вы порекомендовали бы?

Comment: Я может чего не знаю, но емип Swagger не документирует код, он документирует API.

Comment: Я с ним только начинаю разбираться. Касательно документации при понятно, но хотелось бы еще и код задокументировать. Может подскажите решения какие нибудь которые позволяли бы комментарии к коду в документацию преобразовать? По мимо контроллов

Comment: Не знаю, может вы не в курсе [xml комментариев](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)? И там по ссылкам смотрите DocFX и Sandcastle.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не могу найти информацию по генерации документации из XML файлов. Читал много что DocFx умеет это делать но повсюду пересылки идут на то как размечку делать и прочие, а мне нужно что бы он сам подхватил XMl документацию. Может Вы встречали мануалы по этому ?

Comment: Я думаю, следует переформулировать вопрос как-то так: "Как сгенерировать документацию по xml-комментариям?" Тогда могут откликнуться те, кто использует DocFX, GhostDoc и т. п.